# Is iOS Data Protection compatible with the Parse local datastore?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Apple offers the [Data Protection capability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1) to apps which encrypts data stored on the device when the device is locked. The Parse iOS local datastore is apparently [stored as an unencrypted sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27435870/4139760). Is it possible to apply the required Data Protection attributes to the local datastore, specifically `NSFileProtectionComplete`? The [Parse iOS docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#local-datastore-security) don't say anything about this.

I have already applied the appropriate CLPs and ACLs to my Parse classes/objects. I'm looking into iOS Data Protection so that if a user's phone is lost or stolen and a device passcode is in place, the data inside their local datastore cannot be read.